# Plotting with QGIS, blank positions result in errors

Tags: qgis, csv, plot

I tried to use the delimited text layers, then I found something wrong. Several plots are out of bound. Then I checked the original data and decoded data. It seems when one part of a single data is missing, the decode process makes a mistake.

For example, the data should look like this in the original part.
[image]

However, here's the corresponding decoded version in the QGIS. It seems because one colomuns are missing, the compiler uses the coming columns to make up the blank. I don't want to see this, how should I deal with this? I'm kind of a QGIS Noob :( 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if you would [edit] your question to include some of the original raw CSV in text format.

Comment: It looks like ectremely disorder in text version.

Comment: QGIS won't use other columns to make up a null value if you have a comma there but a text field containing a comma will throw it off as it will see that as a field delimiter.  I would opening the text file in Excel and do a global replace of all commas to something else, or re-export from Excel using a different field delimiter (you can tell qgis what delimiter to use on import).  Check this first and then let us know if the problem still exists.